# Nginx and Aegir installation on Ubuntu fails

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, aegir

I am installing Aegir with Nginx on vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 VPS following:
http://community.aegirproject.org/content/installing/manual/nginx-mariadb-php-fpm-single-server-installation

At the very end, during Aegir install I get following error:

```
Could not rsync from '/var/aegir/config/server_master/nginx/subdir.d' to 'aegir@ nginx.drophost.eu:/'                                 [error]
/var/aegir/config/server_master/nginx/subdir.d could not be synced to remote server  nginx.drophost.eu. Changes might not be available[error]
until this has been done. (error: ssh: Could not resolve hostname  nginx.drophost.eu: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0])
```

Server domain is nginx.drophost.eu and it resolves correctly to server IP, so what's wrong?

Comment: error: ssh: Could not resolve hostname  nginx.drophost.eu: Name or service not known.  You should probably investigate that. do nslookup nginx.drophost.eu and see if your dns can resolve this. ( on the computer that you do your isntallation)

Comment: DNS seems to be ok.
root@nginx:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:ca:15:7c
          inet addr:108.61.198.96  Bcast:108.61.199.255  Mask:255.255.254.0


root@nginx:~# nslookup nginx.drophost.eu
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   nginx.drophost.eu
Address: 108.61.198.96

Comment: It resolves it fine for me too, but did you actually try to resolve it on the machine you're performing the install on ?

Comment: Yes, tested on the same machine. I even added this domain and IP to /etc/hosts

Comment: Hmm. I noticed there is also a space between @ and nginx.  Curious if that could be the issue.

Comment: Bingo! :) There was extra space in hostname <facepalm>

Comment: Hah. Glad it worked out.